# attiny85 drops voltage level on an output pin... why?

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement, attiny

I am in the process of building a wireless transmitter that is driven by an attiny85. I have programmed the MCU to encode the data using Manchester encoding and I have used an oscilloscope to show me the wave form that results on the output pin of the MCU when I send 2 bytes of data.

This is literally my first measurement I ever took with an oscilloscope, so I could really use some help interpreting the results. The encoding looks correct, except that the whole wave form is linearly dropping down on the screen! The amplitude of the pulses stays the same, but the ground level drops almost a volt over the ~70ms.

[image]

The MCU is powered by AA batteries and there is nothing hooked up to it except the 10X oscilloscope probe on the output pin.

What does this mean? How can the ground level drop? Is this really happening, or is something going on with the way I am taking the measurement?

Comment: Do you have scope input set to AC or DC coupling? (press menu for CH1, at the bottom of the screen you will see a box with "coupling" - this should say DC. If it doesn't, press the H1 button underneath and set it to DC)

Comment: Could also be that you need to tweak your scope compensation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that channel set to "AC coupling" instead of "DC coupling".  Every scope will have these settings, although there are lots of different ways they can be set.  High end scopes may have a selector knob.  Newer and lower end scopes will probably have a menu selection for that.  Look around in the choices you get associated with the "channel" that you have the scope probe plugged into.

Comment: That is exactly right - I accidentally set the channel to AC Coupling while exploring the controls. Set it back to DC and my wave form is behaving now. Thanks!